# What is Telemetry?

Tags: communication

What Is telemetry? I understand that telemetry is used for measuring, transmitting and receiving. I have two questions:

- Is my assumption correct or not.
- Where is telemetry used and what is its main functionality?

Is telemetry used for only measuring or for the transmission of data from one place to another?
I mean that the telelmetry is used where there is no proper communication or remote places or where the communication system was destroyed due to natural disaster?

Comment: Typically a one way stream of data from a system that will be analyzed by another system after the fact.

Comment: @kenny- Can you check my question which I edited now and thanks for your comments

Comment: "The media" don't use telemetry as journalists aren't remote sensors.  "The media" tend to use satellite phones and video links.

Comment: This strikes me as the kind of thing that should be answered oneself with a little online or even library reading.  There's little point in having people duplicate such resources on a question and answer site.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Telemetry is the obtaining of data and information (e.g., from sensors) from a remote location and the transmission of that data to a local system which can process and/or disseminate it.

From Wikipedia:

> Telemetry is a technology that allows measurements to be made at a distance, usually via radio wave transmission and reception of the information. The word is derived from Greek roots: *tele* = remote, and *metron* = measure. Systems that need external instructions and data to operate require the counterpart of telemetry, *telecommand*.

While Wikipedia cites radio waves, telemetry also encompasses the data from any system which uses remote sensors however they are communicated with - e.g., through the internet, or other wired or abstracted media.

Comment: @Majenko- Its great you answered to my question but I want some clarification so please check the question which I just edited.

Comment: @Gouse - I think this answer covers both sections of your question quite well.

Comment: @RoryAlsop-Sorry I didn't get you. What both sections your talking about? Can you elaborate.

Comment: Telemetry is telemetry whatever the medium it is transferred over - be that over telephone wires, FM transmissions, satellite communications, whatever.  It is still telemetry and it is still the same.